# display 10 items in a single row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I rendering a bubble chart in a div. I need to display only 10 bubbles for large screen and the number of bubbles for a row reduces as the screen size decreases. I tried giving width 10% for each bubble it worked for large screens but it is not responsive.

```css
.chart-padding{
  padding: 20px;
}

.ten-bubbles{
  width: 10%;
}

.qs {
  top: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  /* display: flex; */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -9px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid border" style="background-color: white;width:90%;">

  <ng-container *ngIf="analytics.length > 0">
    <div class="row chart-padding">
      <div class="ten-bubbles col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="cursor: pointer; height: 70px;" *ngFor="let prof of analytics;let i=index"
        (click)="selectedQstn = i">
        <span class="qs">Q{{i + 1}} <a href="#question-view"></a></span>
</div>
</div>
</ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet seem not to be complete (missing Angular?)

Anyway, I can see two choices here:

1. Use Flexbox (and perhaps replace `width` with `flex-basis` for `.ten-bubbles`) with `flex-wrap: wrap` on `.qs`.
2. Use `@media` queries to overwrite the `width` for different viewport sizes. Perhaps you want to scale up instead of down (i.e. design first for mobile and then larger viewports).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the number of bubbles visible up to 10, but add another row, the width of the bubbles had to depend on size of the grid cell where they are placed in. Then you rely completely of the grid responsiveness.

If you would like to reduce the effective number of bubbles visible, you could add a conditional rendering option to reduce the number of bubbles present on smaller screens:

```
<div class="ten-bubbles col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="cursor: pointer; height: 70px;" *ngFor="let prof of analytics;let i=index"
    (click)="selectedQstn = i">
    <div ng-if="i <= 7; else hideOnSmallScreen">
        <span class="qs">Q{{i + 1}} <a href="#question-view"></a></span>
    </div>

    <!-- hide the last 3 elements on medium screens-->
    <ng-template #hideOnSmallScreen>
        <span class="qs d-md-none">Q{{i + 1}} <a href="#question-view"></a></span>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```